# If column F contains string, then return string in column E

Tags: excel, google-sheets

First, thank you all for your help! I have been googling an answer but haven't found one yet. So for example:

[image: Spreadsheet]

In the image above, I am trying to populate column K with the name of the person in column E.

The way I was thinking about this was using the name in column I to search for in column F. If found then return name in column E.

So K1 would return May, K2 would return May AND Jess, K3 would return Jess.

How would I do this? I am working in Google Sheets if that is helpful or not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Good question, use something like:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(F1, I1), CONCATENATE(F1, " AND ", I1), I1)
```

If you don't want to handle the else condition, just substitute the last argument with the original searched cell id.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! When using that formula, I am only getting one value in column K. So for example K2 should return the names both Jess and May, but is only returning May. How would I get multiple values returned?